# IOError exception not handled within signal handler

Tags: sensor, signal

I am usig a RPi as a datalogger for an accelerometer, the ADXL345 breakout from Sparkfun. Since I need the accelerometer to sample at an exact frequency of 200Hz, I am using a signal to trigger the sampling every 0.005 seconds. The results for the x,y and z axis are logged to a csv file, the name of which is "acc" followed by the date and time when the script starts. At the moment the script just runs for 30 minutes and then stops. My initial code worked fine except that every so often an IO error would occur which would kill the program. To fix this, I tried to handle this type of error using a try-except routine so that the the program would just miss some samples and then recover. My code is as follows:

```
    import signal
    from adxl345 import ADXL345
    import time
    import datetime
    adxl345 = ADXL345()

    filename=str('acc_')+str(datetime.datetime.now())

    def handler(signum, frame):
            try:
                    axes = adxl345.getAxes(True)
                    texttowrtite=str(time.time()) + "," +str(axes['x'])+","+str(axes['y'])+","+str(axes['z'])+"\n"
                    f = open('/home/pi/Desktop/'+filename+'.txt', 'a')
                    f.write(texttowrtite)
                    f.close
            except IOError as e:
                    print"I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno,e.strerror)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)

    signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0.005, 0.005)

    start = time.time()

    while (time.time() - start) < (30*60):
            time.sleep(1)

    signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0) # Disable the alarm
    # I/O error(5): Input/output error
```

The problem is that instead of handling the error and then continuing to take samples, it seems that the signal handler stops getting and logging data from the accelerometer. Essentially, once an IO error occurs,  the code just does nothing until the thirty minutes are up.

Can anyone see where I've made an error. This is my first time using both signals and error handling and I can't figure out what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 1):

The actual error is probably the call to f.closed rather than the intended f.close.

f.close will close the file.  f.closed will return a Boolean indicating if the file is open or not.

The script presumably fails when it runs out of file descriptors or memory.

Comment: Hi Joan, I did indeed mean to use f.close. Thanks. Having fixed that, I'm still getting the same behaviour though. Some times it happens after a few seconds or sometimes after a few minutes, but it just stops executing the signal handler code.

Comment: It may be that you are expecting too much of Python.  The string formatting may be consuming memory which never gets a chance to be garbage collected because of the 200Hz processing.  You could  test that theory by changing the delay to 0.05 for a 20Hz update.  If regular timing is important you are going to need to convert the program to C.  Python has too much going on in the background.